# __asm .set doesn't compile in Visual C 2010?

Tags: windows, visual-c++, assembly

I am using Visual C 2010, and have no issues getting `__asm` code to compile with most assembly instructions, e.g.

```
__asm { 
mov eax, eax 
call L1
}
```

but for whatever reason `.set`, or `.long` don't work,  e.g.

```
    __asm { 
    .set SOMETHING 0x000fff
   .long NUMBER

    }
```

The compiler says syntax error, expecting opcode. How do you use `.set` with Visual C's `__asm`?

Comment: It is not a full-blown assemblier.  You cannot use assembler directives.

Comment: @HansPassant is there any way to include assembler directives into my C program, perhaps thru some other means? e.g. is it possible to include .asm source into a C program?

Comment: There's no need to put constant values in inline assembly because that code has access to your C variables. Just define the constant data in C. If you want to use full assembler syntax then compile a .ASM file and link it to your project.

Comment: Try to describe what you really want to do. There is really no need to use things like that in inline assembler.

Comment: If all else fails, you could assemble separately and link it in.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h70hd396.aspx